# Does Plone have a limit on the size of data being uploaded

Tags: plone, zope

I developed a Plone site and I am using csvreplicata add-on to upload data from csv files. I managed to upload a file of about 6000 rows, however when I try to upload a csv with about 120,000 rows the plone site hangs. Does anyone know if there is a limit on the size of data uploaded please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [product code](https://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/Products.csvreplicata/trunk/Products.csvreplicata/Products/csvreplicata/replicator.py) i can't see any transaction savepoint, so I think that the real issue here is that your server goes out of memory because of the huge size of the single transaction and it hangs because it starts swapping. Try to monitor your server's memory usage and if necessary add this code every N elements processed during your import:

```
import transaction

...
transaction.savepoint(optimistic=True)
```

This will make a "sub-transaction" of the transaction, moving data from memory to the hard disk.

Be sure to choose an appropriate N dimension: for very huge transactions you risk to save your memory and going out of disk space because every savepoint multiplies the data dimension on the hdd.

More info: http://docs.zope.org/zope3/Book/zodb/savepoints/show.html

Comment: Could you please give me an indication as to where should I add the code as I am a beginner in python. I tried adding it within def _csvimport inside the try statement just before the exceptions but after I restarted Zope the Plone site did not start.

Comment: So did you monitor your server and it runs out of memory?! If so, I would place the import at the beginning of the module and a save point after the start of the main loop at line 239 (method _csvimport). After that, you should monitor again your memory and disk space. Maybe insert also a print that lets you know which number of iteration it's going on.